# What Is the best way to access and organize instances of class objects in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, javascript-objects

On document.ready, let's say i loop through and I instantiate a bunch of front end Car objects based on existing div element ids.  For example my divs would look something like this

```
<div id='car_' + car_id  + '>
```

Then I loop through and create Car objects....

```
var carIds = $('id^=car_]');

for(i = 0; i < carIds.length; i ++){
   var newCar = new Car($(carIds[i].attr('id'))
}
```

With my Car class I have a method called #setRegistration that takes a string and makes it a property of my instance of Car but it's not set during construction of the object.

In order to access those objects and add the registration later on to a specific Car Object, would I create an array of car objects that I can search through for when the time comes to set the registration?   Is that bad practice especially if the array will potentially contain thousands of objects?

Thanks!

Comment: Rather than array you would be better with object.. A main object with key and value .. so it's easy to access your data

Comment: Also `new Car(carIds[i])` would be `new Car($(carIds[i]).attr('id'))`

Comment: Thanks for the reply!  Would it be best to make a separate Organizer class that keeps up with all my different objects instances and then pass that Organizer object to the classes that need to be organized?

Comment: Yes.. sounds good..